# install4j: is it possible to have full update experience for all medias?

Tags: install4j

I am building my app using install4J and I am now trying to implement updater functionality. I have multiple media and I end up with different result:

- for windows installer (.exe):  it works perfectly, new media is donwloaded, my app is closed and new installer is run automatically
- for .deb, .rpm the new media is downloaded in /Downloads and updater stop there. Is it possible to configure the updater to have my app closed and .deb / .rpm installed automatically similarly to what is achieved for windows updater?
- archive (both windows and unix) the new media is downloaded in /Downloed and updater stop there. Is it possible to configure install4J to have the app closed and to have the .zip / .tar.gz unziped in the app directory to perform the update.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update downloader is just a template and you can modify the screens and actions as you like.

For DEB and RPM you could add actions to the update downloader to install them. For archives on Unix this it is also possible to extract them to the installation directory.

However, on Windows, it is is difficult to do this for archives, because of file locks. Replacing the install4j runtime or a bundled JRE will not be possible because they are in use by the update downloader.

Comment: > For DEB and RPM you could add actions to the update downloader to install them. For archives on Unix this it is also possible to extract them to the installation directory.....

Do pre-defined actions exist for this in install4? I could not find anything suitable ...

Comment: No, you would have to use "Run executable" actions to call the native package managers.

Comment: thank you,  I imagine the download folder is accessible with a variable I could pass to the scipt ...I will give it a try

Comment: similarly to what is done for the installer, is it possible to have a callback when  EventType AFTER_DOWNLOAD is fired ? Something to allow me from my code, to take back the hand when dowload is complete/succesull or control of next steps in case of .deb/.rpm/.zip...

Comment: The updater downloader contains a ""Download file" action, you can add actions after that one. The target file is saved to `${installer:updaterDownloadFile}`.

Comment: in my Java code, I tried `(String) com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables.getInstallerVariable("updaterDownloadFile");` but it returns null

Comment: That method can only return response file variables. By default, the update downloader does not write to the response file. You would have to persist that variable yourself. However, the additional actions that make use of that variable should be directly added in the update downloader and nor in your launcher.

Comment: I tried to select the option register for response file (https://pasteboard.co/JkfvIfL.png) but same results. Also when you say `[...] that variable should be directly added in the update downloader and nor in your launcher`, does it means it is not possible to get that variable in my java app similary to the variables declared in general settings ? I am sorry but it is not clear to me if I am doing it incorretly or if I am trying someting impossible because not supported as it seems there is nothing similar to com.install4j.api.update_downloader.Variables.getVariable() ...

Comment: I just discovered that I have the option to create a "unix installer" media. Which I believe will manage update directly  (shame)

Comment: The update downloader does not persist any installer variables by default. You would have to select the "Register for response file" property of the action named "Download URL" in the update downloader and then add a "Modify a response file" action that saves the variable to the response file. Its "Add response file variables" property has to be selected.